# Force reflow of the DOM container for a resized SVG element in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg, reflow

See the problem in action: http://jsfiddle.net/krtGd/1/

I have an embedded SVG element in a floating `div`, something like this:

```
<div style="float: left;">
    <svg width="50" height="20" id="svg1">           
    </svg>
</div>
```

This works fine; the `div` fits as expected around the SVG. However, when I resize the SVG with JavaScript, like so:

```
$('#svg2').attr('width', 50);
```

...the SVG resizes properly, but the box around it doesn't. As you can see in the jsFiddle, the same thing is true if the containing `div` has `display:inline-block` instead of a float style.

The weird thing here, and what's convincing me that this is a reflow problem and not a simple layout problem, is that if you inspect the either of the problem elements in the Chrome console Elements Panel, the `div` elements resize correctly. This problem may only apply to Google Chrome - I'm seeing it in **Chrome OSX v.20.0.1132.57**, but not in Safari. I haven't tested in FF or IE.

So: **How can I force reflow in Chrome?**

I have tried the usual suspects, including inspecting `div.offsetHeight`, `svg.getBBox()`, and several other variants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a bug in Chromium. When the intrinsic width/height of an svg element change, the layout width/height aren’t automatically changing. You can manually set the layout width/height though: `.css("width", "50px")`. Have you considered filing a bug with Chromium?

Comment: Ah! I hadn't realized that setting the css style would work where the attributes didn't. That looks promising!